# support in non latin fonts in centos

Tags: pdf, fonts, centos, non-latin

I'm trying to enable export html to pdf in my language (Hebrew).
The html and export work fine on my local machine (Mac).

I'm using https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/

On the remote machine(Centos7)
The html works with the Hebrew fonts but the export to pdf outputs this

[image: PDF OUTPUT]

I've tried following:
 1.

```
<head>
    <meta name="pdfkit-page-size" content="Legal"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/webapp/plugins/manual/pdf.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

2. `sudo yum install curl cabextract xorg-x11-font-utils fontconfig`
3. `sudo yum install liberation-sans-fonts`
4. `sudo yum install dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts` (from: https://gist.github.com/drakakisgeo/7591660)

None worked.

The output of `locale`

```
[my_user@ip-172-31-34-70 ~]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the remote server didn't have the right fonts.

I have also solved this by just copying `Arial.ttf` from my local mac in `/Library/Fonts`

```
scp -i "$STAGING_CERT_PATH" Arial.ttf root@"$STAGING_IP":/usr/share/fonts/local/
```

to my remote server to `/usr/share/fonts/local` (created the `local` dir myself).

then `fc-cache -v` to update and it worked

Answer (score 1):

try this one `yum install cjkuni-uming-fonts`